# Why do I have kernel 3.8.0-32 in Ubuntu 12.04 instead of 3.2.0-55?

Tags: 12.04, kernel

With a freshly installed ubuntu 12.04 on my dell xps 13,

```
$ uname -r
3.8.0-32-generic
```

On another laptop,

```
$ uname -r
3.2.0-55-generic
```

I wouldn't care if not for that low brightness bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1163720, that is only fixed with 3.2 ... and which makes the laptop pretty useless.

The only hint of reason I can think of that could explain that kernel is that I had to execute `boot-repair` on my xps (because UEFI mess ...) which asked me to execute some commands .. forgot which ones .. I know I added a PPA ..

OT: I tried 13.10 on my xps, low brightness bug also, plus some indefinable display issue that I can't even google or ask for since it's indefinable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12.04.3 fresh updated iso ships with 3.8 kernel,but you can easily revert it back to 3.2

Just remove linux-image-generic and linux-headers-generic packages and install same one,but this time for 3.2 kernel version